# Is it possible to change the name of a parameter in a PostgresQL function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I have a Postgres function defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_test_function(query_since timestamp) RETURNS TABLE () ...
```

Can I update the name of the parameter, `query_since`, to `query_from` without dropping the function?

The [documentation for `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)  makes it clear that I can not change the argument types using this SQL command. While it does not specifically mention argument names, I suspect the same restriction applies.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct. You can't change the parameter name without dropping and recreating. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0a40e97addf10dd7a37195576eca4f15

Comment: Thanks.  Why not make this an answer?

Comment: Erwin beat me to it and his answer is better then my comment anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Checking the manual: it does, in fact, mention the same restriction for argument names in the [***Description*** section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-DESCRIPTION):

> To replace the current definition of an existing function, use `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`. It is **not possible to change the name or
> argument types of a function this way** (if you tried, you would
> actually be creating a new, distinct function).

Bold emphasis mine.

Either way, since you can refer to parameter (argument) names inside the function body in PL/pgSQL or SQL functions, simply renaming is typically not a sane option to begin with.